# Image won't center in HTML

Tags: html, css

I fail to get the image (logo) in the center of the top bar!! I tried everything, I used `align-self: center;` , `display:block;` but no luck!! I don't know what i'm missing here!

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-raman-npt8zq?file=/index.html) Link to the code for better viewing

**The code:**

```html
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <meta name="keywords" content="مر​حبا">
          <meta name="description" content="">
    
        <style>
          .mail {
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: center;
            align-items: center;
          }
          .headerContainer{
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            align-self: center;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            background-color: black;
          }
          .logo-image-cont{
            align-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            align-self: center;
          }
          .logo-image {
            width: 20%;
            height: 10%;
          }

    
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div class="mail">
            <header class="headerContainer">
              <div class="logo-image-cont">
    
                  <img
                    src="https://i.ibb.co/jwjBMnS/Kia-logo.png"
                    class="logo-image"
                  />
   
                </a>
              </div>
            </header>

          </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: if the logo is a stand alone element , then the code you would need can be shorten to : `headerContainer{
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            background-color: black;
          }
          .logo-image-cont{
             text-align:center
          }
          .logo-image {
            width: 20%;             
          }` flex doesn't need to be involved here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
.logo-image-cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="keywords" content="مر​حبا">
  <meta name="description" content="">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tajawal:wght@200;300;400;500;700;800;900&display=swap');
    .mail {
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .headerContainer {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      align-self: center;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    .logo-image-cont {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .logo-image {
      width: 20%;
      height: 10%;
    }
    
    .emailSection {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-self: center;
      align-content: center;
      font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mail">
    <header class="headerContainer">
      <div class="logo-image-cont">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/jwjBMnS/Kia-logo.png" class="logo-image">
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="emailSection" id="sec-3cf1">
      <div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="emailFooter">
      <div class="footerCopyrightCont">
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
display: flex;
justify-content:center;
```

inside your `logo-image-con` `div` block

[Link to corrected code](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-dew-eyb2yx?file=/index.html:914-969)

Answer (score 0):

add `text-align: center;` to `.logo-image-cont`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the css class with this

```
.logo-image-cont{
            align-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            align-self: center;
            display: flex;
          }
          .logo-image {
            width: 20%;
            height: 10%;
            margin: 0 auto;
          }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <meta name="keywords" content="مر​حبا">
          <meta name="description" content="">
    
        <style>
          .mail {
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: center;
            align-items: center;
          }
          .headerContainer{
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            align-self: center;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            background-color: black;
          }
          .logo-image-cont{
            align-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            align-self: center;
            display: flex;
          }
          .logo-image {
            width: 20%;
            height: 10%;
            margin: 0 auto;
          }

    
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div class="mail">
            <header class="headerContainer">
              <div class="logo-image-cont">
    
                  <img
                    src="https://i.ibb.co/jwjBMnS/Kia-logo.png"
                    class="logo-image"
                  />
   
                </a>
              </div>
            </header>

          </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```